# Measure Theory: construct a finite measure on R

Tags: measure-theory

a question from my homework:
Can we construct a **finite** measure on the **real line** that gives every **rational** number a strictly positive measure (as a singleton).

I'm thinking this a trick question, and since the Sigma Algebra isn't specified, I can construct the measure on the algebra containing all the rationals and punctured lines (that is the whole line minus a finite number of rationals). This is indeed an Algebra.

Let Qn be an enumeration of the rationals. Let every rational singleton {qn} be of measure 1/n^2. The measure of the whole line is then the sum of measures of all the qn's which is finite.
Every punctured line will have the measure of R minus the measure of the qn's removed from it.

Does this make sense or did I go to far and the answer is a simple no?

Thanks for the help! (also sorry I don't know latex)

Comment: Any convergent sum with positive terms works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this by giving $\mathbb{R}$ the discrete $\sigma$-algebra (that is, every subset is measurable). We then can use your idea to define a measure $\mu$: given an enumeration $(q_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of the rationals, for $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ we define
$$
\mu(A):=\sum_{n:\ q_n\in A}\frac{1}{2^n}
$$
(Your choice of $\frac{1}{n^2}$ also works; I use $\frac{1}{2^n}$ because this builds a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes: Assign every rational number a small weight, so that the sum of the weights is finite (e.g. scaled point mass, and similar to what you did). Then define

$$\mu(U) = \left\{\text{sum of weights of rationals in } U\right\}$$

Can you show that this is a finite measure, and find the relevant $\sigma$-algebra?